# Splitting two lines of different .shp files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, splitting

how to split two lines of different shape files at their point of intersection in arcgis 9.x.the manual split is not giving a good split point as snapping is not that good in 9.3, even after tolerance.

Comment: Precisely how are you trying to perform these splits?  At the moment I think you are providing too few details, especially since you are using a version that has not been in common use for nearly 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

A. Split Line at Point method

1. Use the `Analysis Tools > Overlay > Intersect tool` to find the points where the lines intersect and generate a feature class of type Point. That is, the tool’s Output Type field is set to Point.
2. Use the output points in `Data Management Tools > Features > Split Line at Point tool` to break apart the lines at the point locations *(this tool requires an Advanced license)*.

B. Use QGIS Split Lines with Lines Tool *(in case you don't have Advanced ArcGIS License)*

Go to `Processing -> QGIS Algorithms -> Vector Overlay Tools -> Split Lines with Lines`. Then you need to define the input line shapefile and the intersect line shapefile.